# Объясните правило

Tags: правописание

В каких случаях пишется "на счет", а в каких "насчет"? Казалось бы, что раздельно в том случае, когда вопрос касается именно денег, но...

---

*Лаврецкий не был молодым человеком; он не мог долго обманываться на счёт чувства, внушенного ему Лизой; он окончательно в тот же день убедился в том, что полюбил её. И. С. Тургенев, «Дворянское гнездо», 1859.

---

Ну, известное дело, говоря в обществе, а особенно с дамами, хочешь пощеголять своим умом, потешиться, посмеяться, поострить, разумеется не на свой счёт, а на счёт ближнего. М. Н. Загоскин, «Москва и москвичи», 1842—1850 г.*

---

Помогите разобраться...

Answer (score 2):

У Тургенева отражена старая орфография. Там сейчас тоже положено писать слитно.

А для проверки есть правило (не авбсолютное, но помогает). Если можно вставить "на этот счет" - то раздельно.

Comment: Значит, тут просто устаревшая форма?

Comment: У Тургенева - да. Старая орфография. Что такое "форма" в таком контексте не совсем понятно.

Answer (score 2):

Предлог с изъяснительным значением  НАСЧЕТ пишется слитно, он близок по значению к предлогу О, которым его можно заменить при проверке.  У Ожегова: НАСЧЁТ   кого-чего,  предлог  с   род.   п.  Относительно,   по  поводу кого-чего-н., касаясь кого-чего-н. Осведомиться насчет последних событий. Беседа насчет сына.

Предлог нужно отличать от предложной формы существительного с переносным значением:в отношении кого-н., касаясь  кого-н.  Принять намек  на  свой счет. На этот  счет  (разг.) - На этот счет существуют разные мнения.

Приведенные выражения из художественных произведений мне кажутся устаревшими не только по письму, но и по грамматике, поэтому я не стала бы исправлять их орфографию.